# Not able to start react application - ENOENT: no such file or directory, but its NOT package.json file(The file is present)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am new to react and I was following the official documentation in order to create my first react app - https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

The commands are simple, I have read many post in many forums but I didn't see someone having this problem.

So I installed node.js with version 14.18.0 LTS which is OK as per the documentation in react (Node >= 14.0.0 and npm >= 5.6). Then I ran the 3 commands again from the documentation:

1. npx create-react-app my-app
2. cd my-app
3. npm start

First two commands are executed successfully, but when I run npm start it fails with the following error:

```
$ npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start F:\Programming\my_location\my-app
> react-scripts start

internal/fs/utils.js:259
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\streetzaki96\AppData\Local\Temp;F:'
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1646:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Programming\my_location\my-app\node_modules\temp-dir\index.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1074:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Programming\my_location\my-app\node_modules\tempy\index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\streetzaki96\\AppData\\Local\\Temp;F:'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\streetzaki96\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-05T21_31_51_222Z-debug.log
```

The machine which I am trying to run the code is with Windows 8.1 Pro. I also tried running the same commands on another machine which is with Windows 10 and I don't get any error there.

I tried running npm with verbose `npm start --verbose` to see if I can see something in the log file, but it is the same error message just with more lines of code.

Comment: Hi, have you run npm install ?

Comment: Yes I tried that, but I get the same error

Comment: Then check your terminal, is it inside the same folder where npm modules are? go inside the folder where package.json is, if not found run npm init and then run npm install ( npm uninstall then npm install if its giving error) then npm start

Comment: package.json is there, I already tried these commands based on different post here, but it is still not working. As you can see in the title I mentioned that its not package.json which is missing.

Comment: ok, del package-lock.json, node_modules, go to terminal, reinstall node modules

Comment: No, it's not package.lock that's missing, so why don't you look at and think about what _is_ missing? The traceback says that the temp-dir package is trying to find a suspicious-looking path to your temporary directory that contains both your local temp directory _and_ the drive F. That suggests a problem in your Windows config.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried looking at the PATH variable, but I could not find anything suspicious there. I don't know why it concatenates my temp folder C:\Users\streetzaki96\AppData\Local\Temp with my other drive F:/
Is it something that is configurable in react ?

Comment: If you look at what that package actually does, it gets it from https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir. This is not really anything to do with React, and the temporary directory path is not the same as PATH.

Comment: It seems that my os.tmpdir is not correct:
```C:\Users\streetzaki96>echo %Temp%
C:\Users\streetzaki96\AppData\Local\Temp;F:\Installations\maven\apache-maven-3.6
.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3/bin``` probably this is causing the problem. I will try to change it and run the command again. @jonrsharpe thanks man !

Comment: It worked. The problem was that my environment variable TEMP had invalid value: ```%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp;%MAVEN_HOME%/bin``` for some reason.